# Non-canonical ordering on a Python list comprehension output array

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to get an array in Python 3.5.x to sort some objects by the order a key attribute appears in another array. This is to say:  I have an array X of objects x0, ... , xN with key attribute name. I also have an array of names Y with names n0, ... , nk with k<= N. I wish to do the list comprehension

```
[x for x in X if x.name in Y]
```

however I wish to do so in such a way that it does not order based on the order x appears in X but rather orders by the order x.name appears in Y. So if x0 corresponds to n2 and x2 corresponds to n0, I want x2 to appear first in my array.

---

The specific implementation of my code is below

```
names = []
classes = []
class_dict = {'SC': 0, 'TT': 1, 'P': 2, 'S': 3, 'DB': 4, 'AT': 5}
t_score = 0

while True:
        # This code takes inputs and populates the name list Y

    team = [char for char in chars if char.name in names] #Here is the list comprehension

    for char in team:
        char.compute() #This just populates the attributes .SC et al with values

    for i in range(T):
        t_score += team[i].skills[classes[i]]
        print(team[i].skills[classes[i]])
    print('This team\'s score is {}'.format(t_score))
```

The last block of code computes a team score, but unfortunately because of the comprehension's preferred ordering, it pulls the wrong attributes if you don't input the names in the same order, i.e. if the sample xi aren't listed in order by increasingly indexed nj it reports the wrong score.

---

The form of the custom object in question is below, if that helps (but it shouldn't be relevant):

```
class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, idnum):
        self.name = name
        self.SC = 0
        self.TT = 0
        self.P  = 0
        self.S  = 0
        self.DB = 0
        self.AT = 0
        self.skills = [self.SC, self.TT, self.P, self.S, self.DB, self.AT]
        self.SC_skills = []
        self.TT_skills = []
        self.P_skills  = []
        self.S_skills  = []
        self.P_skills  = []
        self.DB_skills = []
        self.AT_skills = []
```

Comment: It will be simpler to just sort your list after creating it, or sort the initial list X (using some default value like 0 for items with no counterpart in N) before doing the list comprehension.

Comment: @BrenBarn I thought of that, but the list is of a custom object, I'm not sure Python has a canonical ordering for objects which aren't alphanumeric style.

Comment: You can specify any comparison method you want using the `key` argument to `sort`.  It's just that you have to do it on an already-created list, not as part of the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So ... I'm not sure that I completely understand the problem, but it looks like `Y` is a list of names.  You'll do better if you turn it into a dict which maps the name to the index:

```
Y_map = {name: ix for ix, name in enumerate(Y)}
```

Now we can use `Y_map` to filter `X`:

```
X_filter = (x for x in X if x.name in Y_map)
```

And then we can use `Y_map` again to determine sort order of the `X_filter`:

```
sorted_X = sorted(X_filter, key=lambda x: Y_map[x.name])
```